# I am using lazy classifier for my dataset but it returns empty frame

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier

y = np.array(skin_new_df['diagnostic'])
X = np.array(skin_new_df.drop(['diagnostic'], axis=1))
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0, 
                 ignore_warnings=True, 
                 custom_metric = None)
models,predictions = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
print(models)
```

I run this code and get empty frame at the output

(2298, 25)
(2298,)
100%|██████████| 29/29 [00:08<00:00,  3.61it/s]
Accuracy    Balanced Accuracy   ROC AUC F1 Score    Time Taken
Model

I want to get all models accuracy

Comment: If you set `ignore_warnings=False`, it might give you a better insight.

Comment: In my case (using a different dataset), converting the values to np.float32 or np.float64 solved the problem.